# Tag few words from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a HTML page. Is it possible to select (by mouse) few words of a paragraph, get reference to those selected words and encapsulate them, say, by the `<span>...</span>` tag programatically? We can use jQuery or HTML5/CSS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `mouseup` handler and use `getSelection`. Say you have a div called `testtagging`, then this is a way to add a span to a selected text within that div. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/MaUxM).

```
$('#testtagging').on('mouseup',tag);

function tag(e){
    tagSelection('<span style="color:red">$1</span>');
}

function tagSelection(html) {
    var range, node;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
     //IE
     range = document.selection.createRange();
     range.pasteHTML(html.replace(/\$1/,range.text));
     return true;
    }
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) { 
     //other browsers
     range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
     node = range.createContextualFragment(
                  html.replace(/\$1/,range.toString())
            );
     range.deleteContents();     
     range.insertNode(node);
    } 
    return true;
}​
```

[**edit**] adjusted for use with IE too. JsFiddle is also adapted

Comment: Thank you very much, sounds very good. I'll study this code and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/rsTkC/2/)

Propose to wrap all paragraph words into `span` elements:

```
var r = /(\S+)/ig;
var text = $("p").text();
$("p").html(text.replace(r, "<span class='w'>$1</span>"));
```

Then bind hover/click events:

```
$("p > .w").on("hover", function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
})
.on("click", function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

If you want to parse words from selected text range, you should use `window.getSelection()`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse) question or ask me to adapt this code.